# Why 'declare' variables in Python?

Tags: python, variable-declaration

I was Googling some Python-related questions earlier, and stumbled upon [this](http://www.lifeofatechdude.com/2012/01/python-convert-object-to-dictionary.html) page. The author does something like the following:

```
class TestClass(object):
    first = str()
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = "Hello"
```

What's the point of "declaring" the variable `first` like that? I've never seen this done before, and I can't for the life of me think of a situation where it is beneficial to create a variable before assigning it some value.

The above example could just as well have looked like this:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, first="Hello"):
        self.first = first
```

...or am I missing something?

Comment: The example could have, but the results are not *exactly* the same.

Comment: The "first = str()" creates a variable associated to the **class** while the "self.first = ..." creates a new one for the instance (this doesn't mean that it makes sense).

Comment: Just remember: There's probably more horribly *bad* code out there than good one.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read, especially if it's on the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a declaration, that's an assignment ... to a variable inside the class, as opposed to a variable inside an instance.

Consider the following output:

```
>>> class K1(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.attr = 'value'
... 
>>> x = K1()
>>> x.__dict__
{'attr': 'value'}
>>> class K2(object):
...     attr = 'value'
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.another = 'value2'
... 
>>> y = K2()
>>> y.__dict__
{'another': 'value2'}
```

Here `x` is an instance of class K1 and has an attribute named `attr`, and `y` is an instance of class K2 and has a different attribute named `another`.  But:

```
>>> y.attr
'value'
```

Where did that come from?  It came from the class:

```
>>> y.__class__.__dict__
dict_proxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'attr': 'value',
'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'K2' objects>,
'__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'K2' objects>,
'__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x80185b9b0>})
```

That's kind of messy but you can see the `attr` sitting in there.  If you look at `x.__class__.__dict__` there's no `attr`:

```
>>> x.__class__.__dict__
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'K1' objects>,
'__module__': '__main__',
'__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'K1' objects>,
'__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x80185b938>})
```

When you get an attribute on an instance, like `x.attr` or `y.attr`, Python first looks for something attached to the instance itself.  If nothing is found, though, it "looks upward" to see if something else defines that attribute.  For classes with inheritance, that involves going through the "member resolution order" list.  In this case there is no inheritance to worry about, but the next step is to look at the class itself.  Here, in K2, there's an attribute in the class named `attr`, so that's what y.attr produces.

You can change the class attribute to change what shows up in `y.attr`:

```
>>> K2.attr = 'newvalue'
>>> y.attr
'newvalue'
```

And in fact, if you make another instance of K2(), it too will pick up the new value:

```
>>> z = K2()
>>> z.attr
'newvalue'
```

Note that changing x's `attr` does not affect new instances of K1():

```
>>> w = K1()
>>> w.attr = 'private to w'
>>> w.attr
'private to w'
>>> x.attr
'value'
```

That's because `w.attr` is really `w.__dict__['attr']`, and `x.attr` is really `x.__dict__['attr']`.  On the other hand, `y.attr` and `z.attr` are both really `y.__class__.__dict__['attr']` and `z.__class__.__dict__['attr']`, and since `y.__class__` and `z.__class__` are both `K2`, changing `K2.attr` changes both.

(I'm not sure the guy who wrote the page referenced in the original question realizes all this, though.  Creating a class-level attribute and then creating an instance-level one with the same name is kind of pointless.)

Comment: Very thorough answer, and I am accepting it. It seems consensus is the author of that post didn't really know what he was doing...

Answer (score 6):

The fact that the author uses

```
first = str()
```

as opposed to

```
first = ''
```

shows, alongside setting `self.first` in `__init__` anyway, that there that is no purpose in doing this.

Maybe the author is confused and thinks python variable need to be *declared* first -_- (evident when viewing the link)

Answer (score 3):

`str()` is equal to `""`

```
>>> str()
''
```

I think the author wants to show that instance attributes override class attributes having same name. So on executing

```
test = testclass()  
print test.__dict__
```

you'll get:

```
{'second': 'weird', 'third': 'test', 'first': 'Some'}
```

not

`{'second': '', 'third': '', 'first': ''}`

but

```
print testclass.__dict__
```

will print the class attributes:

```
{'__module__': '__main__', 'third': '', 'second': '', '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0xb5fed6bc>, 'first': ''}
```

Comment: simple confusion still sounds more likely :)

Comment: I seriously doubt that was the author's intention.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a little difference between the two examples:

```
class TestClass(object):
    first = 'foo'
    def __init__(self):
        self.first = "Hello"

print(TestClass.first)
```

Output:

```
foo
```

However with:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, first="Hello"):
        self.first = "Hello"

print(TestClass.first)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(TestClass.first)
AttributeError: type object 'TestClass' has no attribute 'first'
```

**Note**: But that doesn't mean that the author's code make sense. Just wanted to point out the difference.